# Spring MVC. Question about visions solution / Design Question

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

[spring 3.0.5] MVC

I have on class like that:

```
public class Address {

  private String street;
  private String city;

  public String getStreet() {
     return this.street;
  }

  public void setStreet(String street) {
     this.street = street;
  }

  public String getCity() {
     return this.city;
  }

  public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
  }
}
```

My function is to rely on the possibility of adding an infinite number of addresses on the site (JSP with spring and form tag). Can somebody give a skeleton of such functionality in the controller?

Comment: What do you mean by infinit? Everything has a limit in the world. do you mean that you need to submit n numbers of instances of type Address? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. The answer is twofold:

## Displaying a list of addresses

```
 @Controller
 public class SomeController {

     @RequestMapping("/somepage.jsp ") 
     public String somePage(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
         List<Address> addresses = ....
         // We can now access the key "addresses" in our jsp
         model.put("addresses", addresses);
         return "/WEB-INF/jsp/somepage.jsp";
     }
 }
```

In your jsp page, you can display the list of addresses using e.g., the `core` jstl lib, here noted using the prefix `c`.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html> 
   ...

    <c:forEach items="${addresses}" var="addr">
        City:   ${addr.city}   <br/>
        Street: ${addr.street}
    </c:forEach>

   ....
</html>
```

## Submitting addresses

If you're looking to submit an undefined number of addresses, that's a little more tricky. What you could do is create a javasript form template which upon a button press or so [creates](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/) two additional form fields. Ensure each form field will get a unique name, e.g., :

```
 <input type="text" name="street_1" />
 <input type="text" name="city_1" />

 <input type="text" name="street_2" />
 <input type="text" name="city_2" />

 ....
```

Then you can iterate the fields using `request.getParameterMap()`, where you construct your address options based on matching names (e.g., street_1 should be associated with city_1 and so forth).

**[EDIT]** To give you an idea of what the javascript could look like, I give you this from the top of my head (note I haven't tested this code, it's there to give you an idea of what it *might* look like).

```
var i = 0; // initialize to how many addresses you initially display
function addAddress() {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var html = '<input type="text" name="street_' + i + '" />' + 
               '<input type="text" name="city_'   + i + '" />';
    form.innerHTML += html;
    i++;
}
```

Then call the javascript when pressing a button:

```
<input type="button" onClick="addAddress();" value="add address" />
```

If you decided to use e.g., [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) this would be even easier. E.g.,

```
var i  = 0:
$("#addbtn").click(function() {
    $("#someId").append(
         '<input type="text" name="street_' + i + '" />' + 
         '<input type="text" name="city_'   + i + '" />');
    i++;
});
```

Comment: @Johan, your solution is right, but I think the guy wants to submit form with undefined number of addresses.

Comment: I think you might be right. I added some additional lines to give an idea what it may look like.

Comment: And how do I program the Add button. Adding a new address and displays the list?

Comment: This is what you wrote is very helpful! And could you give an example implementation in Spring MVC 3.0.5 with annotations?

Comment: This is already roughly the procedure you have to use with spring. Spring only goes so far in helping you out with UI programming.

Comment: This solution is not valid if validation is required on the Controller with Spring. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to validate your own objects. Spring can only validate for you when properly backed by a fixed object, which obviously cannot be the case here.